# How to Deserialize Avro message coming from Event hub with file store schema and store in Data Frame in Azure Databricks

Tags: scala, apache-spark, avro, databricks, azure-databricks

Data Coming from Event Hub is in Avro Format which in Binary/unreadable. Need to convert in readable format in a specific schema.

**Below is the code which is tried:**

```
%scala

// Configuration parameters for connecting to Event Hubs.
// Build connection string with the above information 

val connectionString =  ConnectionStringBuilder("our connection string).setEventHubName(EventHubName).build

val customEventhubParameters = 
  EventHubsConf(connectionString)
  .setMaxEventsPerTrigger(1)

val incomingStream = spark.readStream.format("eventhubs").options(customEventhubParameters.toMap).load()

val messages = incomingStream.withColumn("Body", $"body".cast(StringType)).select("Body")
```

Need to read in user defined .avsc schema and store it in Dataframe for later processing